# Ionic Capacitor Browser closes automatically

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to implement an OAuth2 implicit grant frow with a redirect.

Using the browser like this:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Browser } = Plugins;
await Browser.open({ url: loginUrl });
```

results in navigating to the login page, but then immediately jumping back to the previous (main app) screen. Any idea why? BTW, Angular's Platform.paused observable is getting triggered when opening the url and when jumping back (not-paused) as well

Comment: PS: I know someone wrote a whole lib for authentication with Capacitor already https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2 but I just want to know how the browser plugin works compared to cordova browsertabs

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else stumbles upon this issue:

the problem was only on an Android Emulator, not on a real device. Wiping data in the AVD manager made it work in the Emulator as well.